# Symfony doctrine doctrine:mapping:convert filter is not working

Tags: doctrine, reverse-engineering, symfony4

I need to import database structure from existing database.
I tried with

- doctrine:mapping:import "App\Entity" annotation --path=src/Entity
- doctrine:mapping:convert xml src/Entity --from-database --force

And I have this error :
  Table [tableName] has no primary key

So I would import only tables than I need for my project following this 
topic : [Generating a single Entity from existing database using symfony2 and doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10371600/generating-a-single-entity-from-existing-database-using-symfony2-and-doctrine)

and I have the same error.

Have you got a solution for me please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a 'schema_filter' on the Dbal to only have the doctrine:mapping:import 'see' (or avoid reading from) specific table names.

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        connections:
            user_db:
                # only use for `bin/console doctrine:mapping:import`
                schema_filter: /^(oauth_)/
    orm: # configs...
```

Answer (score -1):

Doctrine requires all tables to have a primary key.

If you can't add primary key to existing tables check here:

[Symfony Doctrine Models for Entity Without Primary Keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8429806/symfony-doctrine-models-for-entity-without-primary-keys?rq=1)

https://medium.com/@joaoneto/solves-doctrine-orm-error-with-tables-without-primary-key-on-mysql-when-mapping-the-database-1ce740610b51